# using a cycle view in top and center a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to using a cycle view in top and center a layout.
as you can see, half of this cycle is inside layout and another half is outside of layout.

How can I make it ? using `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` ?

my orange cycle :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
   <solid 
       android:color="@color/color_light_main_color"/>
   <size 
       android:width="2dp"
       android:height="2dp"/>    
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <YourMainView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:margin_top="1dp"/>

  <YourCycle
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>

<\RelativeLayout>
```